# Is it possible to run an XNA game without .NET or XNA installed?

Tags: c#, .net, xna

I've developed an XNA game that I'd like to show a few people at my school, but unfortunately the school computers don't have XNA or the right version of the .NET frameworks installed. And since they are school computers, I can't just just install them.

My questions is whether it is possible or not to run my game without these installed. I was hoping that I might be able to just copy some DLLs or something onto my flash drive or something similar.

Comment: As far as I know, no, you can't.

Comment: @APShredder, bring in a laptop or use an app that you can see your home pc that doesn't require installation such as showmypc.com

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No - The .NET Framework requires a fairly elaborate installation.  You will not be able to run an XNA game without installing the appropriate framework.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I figured this was probably the answer, but I had to ask anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You can't run your XNA game as-is without the appropriate install. However, there's an open-source library called [SilverSprite](http://silversprite.codeplex.com/) whose goal is to "Run XNA games without code changes in Silverlight 3." Obviously there's *some* coding -- at the least, you need some new startup code -- but they give an intro on their project page and it looks like it would probably be pretty quick to get going.

Of course this would mean anyone who wants to play your game would need the Silverlight plug-in, but if that's available on your school's computers (and it might be), then you'd just need to open a Web browser and point it to your game.

Comment: +1; Sounds like it might or might not work, but would be worth a shot.

Comment: I like this as well, I might try it tomorrow to see if it'll work out well.